# Center an image on top of a div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a div with a bunch of stuff in it and what I want to do is place an image, centered, on top of it. My basic layout looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <img style="display:block; position: absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top:-33px; margin-left:-33px;" src="Images/ajax-loader_001.gif" />
    <!-- a bunch of tables and stuff that doesn't have a conveniently fixed size  -->
</div>
```

The above will center the image in the screen (the image is 66px x 66px BTW), but I want it centered relative to the parent div and "floating" above it. Is there a purely css way of doing this? Needs to work in IE8 and recent Firefox versions.

Edit: just to clarify - I'm looking to center *both* horizontally and vertically and on top of the parent.

Comment: You need to put `position: relative;` on your parent div

Comment: @Scott: Damn, that did it. Thanks. If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just need to put this on your parent div:

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<div>
    <img style="display:block; position: relative; margin:auto" src="Images/ajax-loader_001.gif" />
    <!-- a bunch of tables and stuff that doesn't have a conveniently fixed size  -->
</div>
```

This will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all the absolute positioning stuff and instead do this
    img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

Comment: Absolute position is necessary to take it out of the flow of the document and appear above other elements. Also I want to center vertically as well as horizontally. I'll edit the question to clarify that point.